# View model always empty when submitting form from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am very new to MVC and have seen many similar questions but I can't seem to get this to work. I have an image file and I am trying to select the product that the image applies to from a list of products. I have created a view model that holds a Image object and a SelectList of products. The Image object consists of ID, Filename and ProductID. What I am trying to achieve is selecting the product from a drop down list of products and assigning the ProductID field of the Image to the ID of the selected product.

```
Public Class ProductImageViewModel
    Public Image As ProductImage
    Public ProductList As SelectList
End Class
```

In the get method of my controller I am creating an instance of the viewmodel. I assign the Image object from the database and the ProductList object from an already created list of products, then pass it to the view.

```
    ' GET: ProductImages/Edit/
    Function Edit(ByVal id As Integer?) As ActionResult
        If IsNothing(id) Then
            Return New HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        End If
        Dim Model As New ProductImageViewModel
        Model.Image = db.ProductImages.Find(id)
        If IsNothing(Model.Image) Then
            Return HttpNotFound()
        End If
        Model.ProductList = New SelectList(ProductList, "Value", "Text")
        Return View(Model)
    End Function
```

In the view object it displays the filename and the dropdown list of products. I select a product from the list and click submit, which I was expecting to pass the model back to the Post method of my controller. The code for the view is

```
@ModelType ProductImageViewModel
    @Code
        ViewData("Title") = "Edit"
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml"
    End Code

    <h2>Edit</h2>

    @Using (Html.BeginForm())
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @<div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Product Image</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(True, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
            @Html.HiddenFor(Function(Model) Model.Image.ID)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.Image.Filename, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(Model) Model.Image.Filename, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control"}})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(Model) Model.Image.Filename, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-10">
                @Html.Label("Product", htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                <div class="col-md-10">     
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(Model) Model.Image.ProductID, Model.ProductList, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-8"})   
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(Model) Model.Image.ProductID, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    End Using

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>

    @Section Scripts 
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    End Section
```

This displays correctly and I can selected the required product. When I click submit and put a breakpoint in the post method of the controller then both the Image object and the ProductList object contain nothing.

```
' POST: ProductImages/Edit/5
<HttpPost()>
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
Function Edit(ByVal Model As ProductImageViewModel) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        db.Entry(Model.Image).State = EntityState.Modified
        db.SaveChanges()
        Return RedirectToAction("Index")
    End If
    Return View()
End Function
```

I have tried all the suggestions I have seen in other posts but it always seems to pass an empty model back to the controller. Probably a fundamental misunderstanding of how this is supposed to work but I am at a loss as to what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `Public Property Image As ProductImage` (note the `Property` keyword) - the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot set the value of `Fields`

Comment: That's done it - thanks very much.